# Bash - Multi-character string replacement when strings consist of unknown length but same character

Tags: string, sed, replace, case-sensitive

Assume a multi-line text string in which some lines start with a key-character ("#" in our case). Further assume that you wish to replace all instances of a target character ("o" in our case) with a different character ("O" in our case), if - and only if - that target character occurs as a string of two or more adjacent copies (e.g., "ooo"). This replacement is to be done in all lines that do not start with the key-character and must be case-sensitive.

For example, the following lines ...

```
#Foo bar
Foo bar
#Baz foo
Baz foo
```

are supposed to be converted into:

```
#Foo bar
FOO bar
#Baz foo
Baz fOO
```

The following attempt using `sed` does not retain the correct number of target characters:

```
$ echo -e "#Foo bar\nFoo bar\n#Baz foo\nBaz foo" | sed '/^#/!s/o\{2,\}/O/g'
#Foo bar
FO bar
#Baz foo
Baz fO
```

What code (with `sed` or otherwise) would conduct the desired replacement correctly?

Comment: You should have included an example with just 1 `o` that you did not want replaced to demonstrate the 2-or-more `o`s part of your question. You should also have included a line with multiple sets of `o`s to replace. A line like `Foo box good` would test cases the existing example doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Perl:

```perl
echo -e "#Foo bar\nFoo bar\n#Baz foo\nBaz foo" | perl -pe 's/^#.*(*SKIP)(*F)|o{2,}/"O" x length($&)/ge'
```

Here, `^#.*(*SKIP)(*F)` matches and skips all lines starting with `#`, then `o{2,}` matches two or more `o` chars, and `"O" x length($&)` replaces these matches with `O` that is repeated the match size times (`$&` is the match value). Note the `e` flag after `g` that is used to evaluate the string on the right-hand side.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/IeLkH6):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s="#Foo bar
Foo bar
#Baz foo
Baz foo"
perl -pe 's/^#.*(*SKIP)(*F)|o{2,}/"O" x length($&)/ge' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
#Foo bar
FOO bar
#Baz foo
Baz fOO
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ echo -e "#Foo bar\nFoo bar\n#Baz foo\nBaz foo" | sed '/#/!s/o\{2\}/\U&/'
#Foo bar
FOO bar
#Baz foo
Baz fOO
```

Comment: But does this `sed` command allow for the target character to be replaced with a different character (e.g., "ooo" replaced with "nnn")? I don't think it does.

Comment: @MichaelGrünstäudl: Your chosen example is inappropriate

Comment: @MichaelGrünstäudl Sure, just change the replacement from what was already there to what you would lke for t to be e.g `echo -e "#Foo bar\nFoo bar\n#Baz foo\nBaz foo" | sed '/#/!s/o\+/\Unnn/'` or if lowercase is required, remove `\U` `echo -e "#Foo bar\nFoo bar\n#Baz foo\nBaz foo" | sed '/#/!s/o\+/nnn/'`

Comment: Hatless @MichaelGrünstäudl's point is you can't (easily) write a sed script that will replace N "o"s with N occurrences of some other character. In your response you hard-coded 3 `n`s which obviously wouldn't work if the input contained 2 or 4 `o`s. The OP also only wanted to do the replacement if 2 or more contiguous `o`s were present so `o\+` would need to be tweaked.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for clarifying. It was not clear from the question

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '1{x;s/^/O/;x}
        /^#/b
       :a;/oo+/!b;s/oo+/\n&\n/;tb
       :b;G;s/\n\n(.*)\n.$/\1/;ta;s/\n[^\n](.*\n.*)\n(.)$/\2\n\1/;tb' file
```

In overview, use a designated character or characters (in this case `O`) to replace two or more `o`'s where the start of a line is not `#`.

Prime the hold space with the designated character.

If the line starts with `#`, break out.

If the line does not contain two or `o`'s, break out.

Otherwise, surround the two or more `o`'s by newlines.

Append the replacement character and then replace non-newline characters between two newlines with the designated character.

When all replacements for the current set of `o`'s have been replaced, check for more by continuing as above.

Once all replacements have been found, print the amended line.

---

A solution allowing for multiple replacements:

```
sed -E '1{x;s/^/oOxX/;x}
        /^#/b;
        :a;G;/((.)\2+)(.*\n(..)*\2)/!s/\n.*//;t;s//\n\1\n\3/;tb
        :b;s/\n\n(.*)\n.*$/\1/;ta;s/\n(.)(.*\n.*\n(..)*\1(.))/\4\n\2/;tb' file
```